# Orthogonal basis of $M_2(\mathbb{C})$ with respect to special trace inner product

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the largest value of n for which there exists a set $\{A_1, . . . , A_n\}$ of (distinct)
nonzero matrices in $M_2(\mathbb{C})$ such that $A_i^*A_j$ has trace zero for all $1 ≤ i < j ≤ n$?

(a) 1

(b) Greater than 1 but at most 4

(c) Greater than 4 but finite

(d) $\infty$

If one define an inner product on $M_2(\mathbb{C})$ using trace like that $\langle A,B \rangle=tr(B^T A)$ then with respect to this inner product we have to find the maximum possible set for which the members of that set are pairwise orthogonal. So the answer should be (b) as for finite dimensional space any two norm are equivalent.
Am I going wrong? Please correct me.

Comment: (b) is correct though I don't follow your reasoning.  The point is with a definite hermitian form, (aside from the zero vector) orthogonality implies linear independence, so what is the maximal number of linearly independent vectors (i.e. matrices)  $\in M_2(\mathbb{C})$?